# UnderscoreJS - Pull users from an Array who are part of a group

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have an object of groups:

```
{groupid1: "metadata",
 groupid2: "metadata"}
```

And an array of users:

```
[
 {
  name: "something",
  groups: ["groupid1", "groupid2"]
  ...},
 {
  name: "something else ",
  groups: ["groupid1"]
  ...},
 {
  name: "something else again",
  groups: ["groupid2"]
  ...},
]
```

I want to iterate over the group ids and pull a list of users which match that group id, so I end up with two user lists logged, one for each group:

```
for (group in groups) {
 var userArray = _.pluck(users, function(user) { 
  return user.groups.indexOf(group) > -1;
 })
 console.log(userArray);
}
```

The problem is that this is returning me an array of undefined, rather than an array of user objects. Even just returning the user's name would be good.

Thanks for any help you can give!
For scalability, underscore is the preferred method of solving this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [find items in javascript object array where one of the properties does not match items in another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28049138/find-items-in-javascript-object-array-where-one-of-the-properties-does-not-match)

Comment: Hi Mike, underscore is the preferred method to solve this, rather than a pure JS method.

Comment: Raw JavaScript is almost always going to be more "scalable" than a library.

Comment: I was reading up on server side node & underscore and came across posts that when handling larger arrays (in my case it would be ~1000 users and ~20 groups) underscore has better performance. I'll have another look at this and discuss with my colleague, thank you.

Comment: FYI, Underscore is written in JavaScript, so there's no way it can have better performance than JavaScript, since it is JavaScript :). No big deal, and you've got an answer that uses the library, just thought I'd through it out there.

Comment: Yeah I just assumed the library was doing something smart. Performance is incredible important for this project so I really appreciate your comments, I'll have to take another look at my use of underscore (especially if performance issues arise).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your snippet is that you're using `_.pluck` instead of `_.select`.
Here is the underscore.js solution:

```js
const groups = {
    groupid1: "metadata",
    groupid2: "metadata"
};

const users = [{
        name: "something",
        groups: ["groupid1", "groupid2"]
    },
    {
        name: "something else ",
        groups: ["groupid1"]
    },
    {
        name: "something else again",
        groups: ["groupid2"]
    },
];

_.each(_.keys(groups), group => {
    const usersArray = _.select(users, user => {
        return user.groups.indexOf(group) > -1;
    });
    console.log(usersArray);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

To answer author's another question from this answer's comment:

> I wanted to extend the question to push the results from both into a single array, and not include duplicates

```js
const groups = {
    groupid1: "metadata",
    groupid2: "metadata"
};

const users = [{
        name: "something",
        groups: ["groupid1", "groupid2"]
    },
    {
        name: "something else ",
        groups: ["groupid1"]
    },
    {
        name: "something else again",
        groups: ["groupid2"]
    },
];

let usersArray = [];
_.each(_.keys(groups), group => {
    usersArray = _.union(usersArray, _.select(users, user => {
        return user.groups.indexOf(group) > -1;
    }));
});
console.log(usersArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If I wanted to extend the question to push the results from both into a single array, and not include duplicates, should I open new stack exchange question?

Comment: Hi Shubham, would be brilliant if you could do that please!

Comment: Hey Gary, at first I was trying `_.extend` to do the same but found many other drawbacks of using it on an array. But later came up with this easy solution. Do tell me if this works properly for you.

Comment: Hi, definitely working! Cheers, appreciate the help. I was trying ".concat" and  "_.flatten" but that was keeping duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [docs](http://underscorejs.org/#pluck) `_.pluck()` takes two arguments: list and a property name - you're not providing property name but a function. More importantly though, this is not what you use `_.pluck()` function for (check the documentation again).

In your case, you don't even need to use UnderscoreJS at all:

```js
// Your groups
const groups = {
  groupid1: "metadata",
  groupid2: "metadata"
};

// Your users
const users = [
 {
  name: "something",
  groups: ["groupid1", "groupid2"],
 },
 {
  name: "something else ",
  groups: ["groupid1"]
 },
 {
  name: "something else again",
  groups: ["groupid2"]
 }
];

// Get ids of the groups and loop through them
const result = Object.keys(groups).forEach(groupId => {
  // Return only users whose groups array contains the groupId
  const usersFound = users.filter(user => user.groups.indexOf(groupId) > -1);
  
  // Log the users found
  console.log(usersFound);
});
```

Comment: This looks to be working great, thanks.
Reason for using _.pluck() is because the documentation states it's use is for "extracting a list of property values", in this case the property value was an object - I didn't look properly at the arguments though.